# Integration of Multivariate Normal Distribution in Python

Tags: python, numerical-integration

I am trying to integrate over a multivariate distribution in python. To test it, I built this toy example with a bivariate normal distribution. I use `nquad()` in order to extend it to more than two variables later on. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal


def integrand(x0, x1, mean, cov):
    return multivariate_normal.pdf([x0, x1], mean=mean, cov=cov)

mean = np.array([100, 100])
cov = np.array([[20, 0], [0, 20]])

res, err = integrate.nquad(integrand,
                           [[-np.inf, np.inf], [-np.inf, np.inf]],
                           args=(mean, cov))

print(res)
```

The result I get is `9.559199162933625e-10`. Obviously, this is incorrect. It should be (close to) 1.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scipy's nquad does numerical integration only on bounded rectangular domains. The fact that your integral converges at all is due to the `exp(-r^2)`-type weight of the PDF (see [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.0.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html) for its explicit form). Hence, you need [Hermite quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Hermite_quadrature) in 2D. [Some](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1969-23-108/S0025-5718-1969-0258281-4/home.html) [articles](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1963-17-082/S0025-5718-1963-0161473-0/home.html) exist on this topic, and [quadpy](https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy#2d-space-with-weight-function-exp-r2) (a project of mine) implements those.

You'll first need to bring your integral into a form that contains the exact weight `exp(-r**2)` where `r**2` is `x[0]**2 + x[1]**2`. Then you cut this weight and feed it into quadpy's e2r2 quadrature:

```
import numpy
import quadpy


def integrand(x):
    return 1 / numpy.pi * numpy.ones(x.shape[1:])


val = quadpy.e2r2.integrate(
    integrand,
    quadpy.e2r2.RabinowitzRichter(3)
    )

print(val)
```

```
1.0000000000000004
```

Comment: "scipy's nquad does numerical integration only on bounded rectangular domains"
I didn't know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A bit off-topic, but you should use the following routine instead (it is quite fast):

```
from scipy.stats.mvn import mvnun
import numpy as np

mean = np.array([100, 100])
cov = np.array([[20, 0], [0, 20]])
mvnun(np.array([-np.inf, -np.inf]), np.array([np.inf, np.inf]), mean, cov)
```

Or use `multivariate_normal.cdf` and do the substractions.

Comment: Do not use `scipy.stats.mvn`, it's undocumented, not meant for public use, and will be removed in Scipy 2.0: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/stats/mvn.py