# how to integrating Multivariate Normal distribution Density?

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, gaussian, numerical-integration

I'm trying find a solution to integrate Density of multivariate normal distribution.
I have 100 points dataset (x,y) and a covariance matrix (sigma) of these data
I have an idea to integrate density that I integrate each value of covariance matrix (x[i] to x[j]) and then sum all integrated values. Is it correct?

```
def gaussian(x, mu, sig):
    return np.exp(-(x - mu)**2/ (2 * sig**2))
I = np.zeros(len(sigma), dtype=float)

for i in range(0, len(sigma)):
I[i]  = quad(gaussian, x1[i] , x1[i+1] ,  args=(0, sigma[i]))[0]
sum(I)
```

Comment: I do not think that would work. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49433077/integration-of-multivariate-normal-distribution-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integration of Multivariate Normal Distribution in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49433077/integration-of-multivariate-normal-distribution-in-python)