# How to estimate integral of a bivariate normal distribution obtained with scipy.stats.multivariate_normal?

Tags: python, gaussian, integral

I am trying to estimate the integral of a bivariate normal distribution obtained with scipy.stats.multivariate_normal. The covariance matrix of my distribution is diagonal (independant) with two different variances. Which method would be most appropriate for this function ?

I have been trying to use the module developped by Nico ([Integration of Multivariate Normal Distribution in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49433077/integration-of-multivariate-normal-distribution-in-python/58698818#58698818)).
The documentation of the package : https://pypi.org/project/quadpy/

Nevertheless, I am getting the following error message : "AttributeError: module 'quadpy.e2r2' has no attribute 'integrate'".
Am I missing a module mandatory for quadpy ?

Answer (score 1):

Author here. You'll have to instantiate a scheme, then use that to integrate; see the documentation https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy#2d-space-with-weight-function-exp-r2.

```py
import quadpy

scheme = quadpy.e2r2.rabinowitz_richter_3()
scheme.show()
val = scheme.integrate(lambda x: x[0]**2)
```